# Python 3.5 logger.info in @classmethod

Tags: python, logging

New to python, never user @classmethod before. 
The problem - for some reason `logger` methods are not executed within the `shutdown_webdriver` function.

```
import time
import logging

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy


class WebBrowserSettings(object):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def __init__(self, proxy):
        self.proxy = proxy

    def setup_remote_chromedriver(self):

        **irrelevant code**

        return browser

    @classmethod
    def shutdown_webdriver(cls, browser):
        print('here')
        cls.logger.info("Shutting down 1")
        for index in range(0, 20):
            error_check = 0
            try:
                time.sleep(5)
                browser.quit()
            except Exception:
                error_check = 1

            if error_check == 0:
                break

        cls.logger.info("Browser is down")
```

So i see only the print('here') message in my console output.

P.S. the logging config is setup and stable, working in other classes.

Comment: have you checked if `logger` is None or not?

Comment: not None. logger is working 100%. some prob with the structure maybe..
currently just instantiated `logger` once again in `@classmethod`to make it work

Comment: Were you able to find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the code shown here. I suspect that you will see the logging output when you replace `cls.logger.info` with `cls.logger.error`. This means that something is going wrong with the configuration of the logging system. This is also the part that is not shown here, so I can't tell what is going wrong.

In any case you have to make sure that the logging system is configured to display level `INFO` before the instantiation of the logger instance. 
Your logger gets instantiated at the time the code is being parsed, probably at the time some other code imports this module. 
This in turn means that you have to configure the logging system before you import this module.

Comment: same, i don't see the problem :) however the logging configured properly, tested. Only the problem with this class.

Comment: Can you verifiy this by replacing 'cls.logger.info' with 'cls.logger.error' ? Still no log messages on stdout? I'm pretty sure there will be ...

Comment: ye sure tried with .error / .info / .debug (in logging settings `level=DEBUG`). anyway i see this prob only with this one class... so objectively, my "bad" fix is ok for me.